# What would be the most efficient way to transform json values into json?

Tags: json, python-3.x, string

I am taking in user input that provides JSON values (either a list, a string, or a dictionary, or any combination of these three) and was wondering what the most efficient way to convert these into a list of json values would be.

I already have the user input for multiple lines:

```py
def read_input():
    in = ""
    while True:
        try: line = input()
        except EOFError: break
        user_input += line
    return in
```

And this provides a string of all json values. The trouble I'm facing is how to then turn this string into a single list of json values. I am using json.loads() to convert to json.

For example, if I try:

```py
print(json.loads(read_input))
```

and type in `"cat"` as the input, I get:

```py
cat
```

However, if I type in `"cat" [2]` as the input, I get an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(json.loads(read_multiline_input()))
  File "C:\Users\mmv456\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\mmv456\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)
```

whereas I would expect the output to be: `["cat", [2]]`.

I realize this isn't standard json, instead it is json values, but I would definitely appreciate any tips you have on how to do this. Essentially I would like to take the string of json values and split each by their object so that they are all in a list and then use the json.loads() function.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried `json.loads(read_input.split(" "))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
import json

def read_stream():
  data = []
  while True:
    usr_input = yield
    if not usr_input:
      print(json.dumps(data))
      break
    data.append(json.loads(usr_input))

stream = read_stream()
next(stream)
while True:
  try:
    stream.send(input("Enter value or press <enter> to stop: "))
  except StopIteration:
    break
```

Example output:

```
nter value or press <enter> to stop: "cat"
Enter value or press <enter> to stop: [2]
Enter value or press <enter> to stop:
["cat", [2]]
```